# Excute python script throgh groovy script using job DSL

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy

Referring to the document:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-steps-python
I am trying to configure my job automatically through groovy.
The job will execute a python code piece. Something like this:

```
import os
from Reporting.MSTest import MSTest
jsonFile = os.path.join(os.getenv('temp')
```

Here is the code snippet. Which will add above python script in the job build steps

```
# the job name is "jobName"
jobA = freeStyleJob("jobName")
jobA.with {
    steps {
        python {
            command(String 'import os')
        }
    }
}
```

It not working. Please help!

Comment: The `command` contains the filename for a python script, not python code

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins DSL 'python' refers to the [Shining Panda](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ShiningPanda+Plugin) plugin not the [python script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Python+Plugin) plugin. This is worth bearing in mind if like me you use the python script plugin.

Sadly the python script plugin doesn't have an API but you can use a configure closure to add this direct.

```
configure { node ->
  node / builders / 'hudson.plugins.python.Python' / command << readFileFromWorkspace('<script location>')
}
```

This has worked for me as I like to read from script for simplicity or you could add direct with 'command( 'import os' )'