# Add 'execute python script' as build step while creating a jenkins job using groovy with job dsl plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am working on creating jenkins job from groovy script using DSL plugin apis. I want to add 'Execute python script' as a step in jenkins job. Here is what I am doing following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084145/excute-python-script-throgh-groovy-script-using-job-dsl) post:

```
job('example') {
description('My first job')
displayName('Job DSL Example Project')
properties {
    sidebarLinks {
        // use uploaded image
        link('https://wiki.acme.org/', 'Wiki', '/userContent/wiki.png')
    }
}
steps {
    python{
        command(''' print("Hello")''')
        nature('python')
    }
  } 
}
```

In the generated job, the step added is "Python Builder" step as shown in image below. 
[image: The output I currently getting]
Instead I wanted to have "Execute Python script" step as shown below.
[image: Required output]

Note:I have installed the shining panda plugin.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. [Don't post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind. Can you help me where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job DSL only has built-in support for the Shining Panda plugin and will generate the "Python Builder" build step. The "Execute Python script" build step is provided by the Python plugin.

You can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to add that (or any other) build step:

```
job('example') {
  configure {
    it / 'builders' / 'hudson.plugins.python.Python' {
      command('print("Hello")')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much @daspilker!